# Why are there so many &nbsp; displayed in the Category display?

Tags: categories, ee3

I am running EE 3.4.1 and when adding subcategories to the category interface I am seeing a row of  's in front of all the subcategories in the drop down list - see the attached image.

This seems odd if not just annoying. Is this a bug or is there something causing this that can be corrected on the user side?

[image]

Comment: How are you generating this list? Is this simply a select tag?

Comment: I am entering the content manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a Bug in EE and has been reported to EE.